# Running ActiveMQ Artemis web console in embedded mode

Tags: activemq-artemis

In the artemis example folder, there is a sample that helped me run artemis in embedded mode. This is helpful for me when dealing with unit tests.

Is it possible to view the console in browser (localhost:8161) after running the server in embedded mode.

I found that the console war file is listed in bootstrap.xml file and I tried to place bootstrap.xml file in classpath as well but still not able to run console.

Is it possible to view web console when artemis run in embedded mode?

Comment: Any feedback here? Did you ever get this sorted?

Answer (score 2):

When you run your own embedded instance of ActiveMQ Artemis the `bootstrap.xml` file isn't used. That file is only used by a *standalone* broker. The application which embeds the broker is itself responsible for bootstrapping it (i.e. configuring and passing in all the prerequisites).

By default a *standalone* broker will configure and start an embedded instance of [Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/). It will also deploy the web console WAR to this Jetty instance. All this is defined in `bootstrap.xml`.

However, when you embed your own broker all you get is the broker. If you want a web server in your application to serve any web applications (e.g. the ActiveMQ Artemis web console) then you'll have to embed that yourself as well along with the broker.